# Python argparse Optional argument only works when it's entered in the right positions

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

In my script I have 3 positional arguments and 1 optional argument. One of the three positional arguments is required and the rest is optional (as specified using `narg='?'`).

My optional argument doesn't pass any other arguments (action ='store_true') and is just there to enable sorting which will be implemented at a later time.

However, my problem is that my optional argument only works when it is the first or last argument in the script call.

Below is my script so far:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-s", "--sort", help="option to sort the ip addresses", action='store_true')
parser.add_argument("file_name", help="Name of the file containing the tcpdump")
parser.add_argument("source_IP", nargs='?', type=str, help="Source ip to search") 
parser.add_argument("dest_IP", nargs='?', type=str, help="Destination ip to search")

args = parser.parse_args()
```

If I enter my `-s` between any of the other positional arguments I get an error.

```
 Ex: ./my_script file.txt -s 192.168.152.32 192.168.0.25
```

> usage: 1 [-h] [-s] file_name [source_IP] [dest_IP]
>   1: error: unrecognized arguments: 192.168.152.32 192.168.0.25

My goal is to be able to enter my optional argument (`-s`) anywhere in the script call and have it working.

Comment: It's just not how argparse works. Positional arguments always need to be at the end. If you want it to work differently I think you'll need to roll your own argparse, it shouldn't be difficult for the simple case you present.

Comment: Side-note: `type=str` is the default type for most actions (aside from the weird ones like `store_const`, `store_true`, etc.). You don't need to say they're `str`.

Comment: If all the positionals required arguments, they can be freely intermixed with flagged arguments.  It's the '?` that creates problems in this case.

Comment: its an annoying bug, in some cases I can get away with converting the optional argument to an optional named argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three positional arguments, but two of them are also optional thanks to `nargs='?'`. `argparse` is getting screwed up because it sees the positional filename, and then has to choose arbitrarily between interpreting the `-s` as the optional positional `source`, or as the switch. Either interpretation is valid (it's not doing complicated backtracking parsing to try to find some legal interpretation of the arguments that would allow it to complete; doing so with some argument types could lead to very bad behavior, like opening a file, then backtracking, closing it, and opening something else).

Short answer: In general, optional arguments should be either all positional, or all switches. Mixing and matching introduces complications that would make parsing a complicated recursive process that could only heuristically guess at the correct parsing (particularly with `nargs='*'` and `nargs='+'`, but even `'?'` causes problems as you see). Removing the `nargs` qualifier from `source` and `dest`, or leaving them optional and converting to switches will allow `-s` to be passed in whatever order you like.

Comment: The parser never confuses `-s` with a positional source.  What confuses it is the empty list of arguments between `filename` and `-s`.  Fixing this requires adding some look-ahead to the parsing.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is a subtile one, and requires a good understanding of how `argparse` parses postionals and optionals.

If all the positionals took one argument (the default `nargs`), then the `-s` could occur anywhere - start, end, or between any positional.

What happens with:

```
./my_script file.txt -s 192.168.152.32 192.168.0.25
```

is that `source_IP`,`dest_IP` are both consumed (and set to their defaults) when `file_name` is parsed.  It then handles `-s`.  Now there are 2 strings left, but no positionals to consume them, hence the `unrecognized arguments` error.  Note that `./my_script file.txt` runs fine, as does `./my_script file.txt -s`.  In all 3 cases, the 2 IP arguments are consumed at the same time as `file_name`.

`parse_args` alternates between consuming positionals and optionals.  It will consume as many positionals at time as there strings (think of a greedy regex expression).  Since `source_IP` and `dest_IP` are ok with 0 args, all three are consumed the first time it handles positionals.

There isn't a neat fix for the user, except to be wary of using `nargs='?'` positionals.

There is a bug/issue that tries to fix this.  But the fix isn't trivial.  The parser has to 'look ahead', noting that it could delay parsing these '?' arguments.

```
http://bugs.python.org/issue15112
argparse: nargs='*' positional argument doesn't accept any items
   if preceded by an option and another positional
```

Your parser runs fine with the `argparse` patched as proposed in that issue.  But there's quite a backlog of potential patches for argparse.